# How to setup D3.js axis labels to show rounded numbers with the $ sign?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm looking for a D3 formatter (or alternative solution) to set up axis labels in the following format:

- the value 10000000 should be formatted to '$10m'
- the value 30000000 should be formatted to '$30m'
- etc.

The only thing what I've found and does something similar is *d3.format(".2s")* which converts the values to '10M', '30M', etc.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the dollar sign in front of the number, i.e.

```
d3.format("$.2s")
```